# Google Material Slider 2, centered thumb slider can expands to left and right

Tags: android, material-ui

Trying to archive a slider with range -63 +63 by posistioning the thumb centered on the value 0, moving the thumb on left the track expands it self on the left till -63 value and moving the same thumb on the right the track expand it self till 63 value on the right. to help understand basically I want to archive a PANorama controller over the sound

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="39dp"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="PAN"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
            android:id="@+id/panSlider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:stepSize="1"
            android:value="100"
            android:valueFrom="-63"
            android:valueTo="63"
            app:haloColor="#000000"
            app:haloRadius="0dp"
            app:labelBehavior="gone"
            app:thumbColor="#FF5722"
            app:thumbElevation="0dp"
            app:tickVisible="false"
            app:trackColorActive="#FF5722"
            app:trackColorInactive="#000000"
            app:trackHeight="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/panTextSlider"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:text="100"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
```